# Mark Joomla Content as outdated but leaving it visible

Tags: php, joomla, seo, joomla2.5

**The Issue**
We manage a large number of sites,  these sites are consistently updating and are losing link juice due to archived and expired content.  The managers of these sites archive and expire content that...  could just be flagged as old or greyed out,  provide a nice UX by telling the user the content may not be relevant however leaving the content there for the search engines to keep as well as any inbound links.  Currently they hit a 404.  Which is ok,  but not fabulous.  in two occasions,  the manager has expired content which had a higher page authority than the homepage.

**Ideal fix**
We are looking for a fix  such as the hot deals uk 
http://www.hotukdeals.com/deals/7-piece-tefal-pan-set-for-under-13-1501

There content still works!  but... Its clearly marked as expired and old.  Great from a user point of  view and an SEO point of view.

**final notes**
Before someone shouts out! archive it!!! no,  this creates duplicate links.  Our end users and managers aren't massively teck savvy. We need to utilise a system that has two button process.  Or at least one that we as developers can make into a two button process.  Any ideas would be great

edit;

Version : Joomla 2.5.19

Comment: When you say "archive it" you mean change the state to archived? The point of the archived state is that the item is not returned in lists but is available for search and of course as item links. Don't make an archive link, just use Finder for search.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if there are existing solutions to this out there, there might be. My solution would be to write a content plugin that saves the expired - state of the content article.

I believe you can add the expired - state as a content parameter, by manipulating the form-object in the onContentPrepareForm - function of the content plugin, and adding a expired-checkbox. In the  onContentPrepareData - function, you prepare the expired-data for the form.

regards Jonas

Comment: Ill look into this,  This is kind of the line i was playing with yesterday.  I actually managed to have the content show.  But There was a hand full that still refused.  Going to give this ago once the project is allocated some more time later this week.

Comment: I have looked at existing solutions.  It seems an empty area,  I was rather surprised.  But i guess Joomla wasn't made to be used like this,  in a world where google wants to find the diamonds in the coal.

Comment: You could just have an expired tag that is automatically applied x days after publication using a cron job or manually.